# Which FAA knowledge tests share question database (e.g. Commercial and Advance Ground Instructor)?

Tags: faa, faa-knowledge-test

I'm curious if there is an overlap between tests. I'll be on instrument, commercial, ground instructor, cfi and cfii ratings in sequence and I wonder if I could take similar exams back to back. Thanks

Comment: If you study for the Instrument written you should not need any additional prep for the Instrument Ground Instructor. The Advanced Ground Instructor is similar to private and commercial but also includes questions about other aircraft e.g. rotorcraft, multi-engine, glider, baloons, and I believe sport. It may have questions about drones but I don’t remember. Here are some sample questions. https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/training_testing/testing/test_questions/agi_questions.pdf